# Is their any way to add a movieclip at frame "n" of parent movieclip without gotoAndStop()

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Is their any way to add a movieclip at a frame n ( n > 1) of a parent movieclip, without using gotoAndStop on parent movieclip ?

Thanks
.

Comment: The fact that there is more than one frame in your movieclip indicates there's a timeline.  Why not just add it with the timeline in the ide?

Comment: Wanna achieve it dynamically. For any of my variable class extending Movieclip.

Comment: So, what is the goal of wanting to achieve it dynamically?

Comment: Well, the same goal that all dynamic processes have... ie, loading any movieclip of any class from library directly via code, and not depending upon the IDE but the code. As per trend here where i work, we share fla with designers only.. and never with the coders. Thanks

Comment: No, what is the business case for wanting to do this (an example of a specific thing that this would accomplish)

Comment: I want to invoke "Added" event for knowing the name children movieclips of a parent movieclip. Unfortunately, Added event for contents of any movieclips don't get invoked if they are in the 1st frame. So, i am loading the target movieclip on the nth frame of container. So when playing the container movieclip, the nth frame loads... the Added event get invoked for all the children of target movieclip ( present on the nth frame ). Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5333/discussion-between-vishwas-gagrani-and-amy-blankenship)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MMm, I don't know your setup and your project's structure and limitation, but I think the only thing you can try is:

```
 yourParentMc.addFrameScript(3,frameFunction); // 3 is the frame in which you want to create the other mc(zero based)

 private function frameFunction():void {
      parent.addChild (otherMc);    
 }
```

In this way, when the parent mc whill reach frame 4 (remember, is zero based), the code will addChild the otherMc.

If you want an opinion, this way of structure the code is HIGHLY dangerous and very hard to mantain and to debug....

Comment: Dangerous and hard to maintain and debug... +1